# Talking relationship

Tags: word-request

I have searching for a term that I'm unable to find yet. If I am not talking to my friend or relative but my relationship isn't broken. We two are angry with each other. We will begin talking and meeting as soon as as one of us moves forward. Now what should I say:

1. I am not in talking relation with X.
2. I am not out of communication with x.
3. I am not on talking terms with x.

Answer (score 1):

We are not [currently] on speaking terms.